# Android BitmapDrawable load from url

Tags: android, drawable, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory

If I have the URL String such as `str_URL = "http://........ABC.png";`

How can I add it to below which replace R.drawable.jth?

```
BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.jth);
BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.jthj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't allow to set an URL as a drawable's source directly, you'll need to write your code to download the file and then use a bitmapfactory to create your drawable.

If you don't want to write code to do that, you can use some open source libraries like Koush's [URLImageViewer](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper), if what you want is to display your drawable on an ImageView